# How to get driverName and Port of Network Printer in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, printing, port, driver

I am trying to get Network Printer Driver and Port Name in my QT application. How I can achieve this? I pass my configured printer name that gives the particular printer driver name and port.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `QList<QPrinterInfo> availablePrinters()` you can get all the available printers. In this list, check the return values of `printerName()` and `location()` of the printer that you're interested.